# How to block interaction of showsUserLocation in mapView?

Tags: ios, swift, android-mapview, xcode6

I have

```
 self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
```

in my mapView, and this show a blue circle in my current location, but if I press this circle, this show a message "Current location!. And I dislike show this.. how can I idsabled this message?
        Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to disable the title of the annotation of the user location

```
   self.mapView.userLocation.title = ""
```

IS this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes! I want not show location message and with title = "" I get this. Thanks!!

Comment: happy I am helping someone